# Cocos2d-x 4.0 app build no longer works after upgrade to macOS Big Sur 11.01 (error: no such file or directory: '/usr/lib/libz.dylib')

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, cocos2d-x

After upgrade to macOS Big Sur 11.01 i get the following error:

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/lib/libz.dylib'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/lib/libiconv.dylib'
Command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code

How to reproduce:
make new cocos2d-x project using:

- cocos -n -d dirname -l cpp
- cd dirname/MyCppGame
- mkdir build-iphone
- cd build-iphone
- cmake .. -GXcode -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=iOS -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT=iphoneos

Open the generated xcode project (change bundle identifier) and build

Versions:

- macOS Big sur 11.01
- CMake 3.18 or CMake 3.19.0-rc3
- cocos2d-x v4.0
- Xcode 12.2

Comment: What solution did you use finally?

Comment: I still use the first answer because i use cmake to build the apps (cmake is doing the same). If you only have one or two project you can use the other answers.

Comment: Setting libz each time is tedious, did you find a solution using CMake ?

Answer (score 6):

I changed the file: 'CocosConfigDepend.cmake' in cmake/modules/ of the cocos2d-x v4.0 library.

```
    elseif(IOS)
        # Locate system libraries on iOS
        find_library(UIKIT_LIBRARY UIKit)
        find_library(OPENGLES_LIBRARY OpenGLES)
        find_library(CORE_MOTION_LIBRARY CoreMotion)
        find_library(AVKIT_LIBRARY AVKit)
        find_library(CORE_MEDIA_LIBRARY CoreMedia)
        find_library(CORE_TEXT_LIBRARY CoreText)
        find_library(SECURITY_LIBRARY Security)
        find_library(CORE_GRAPHICS_LIBRARY CoreGraphics)
        find_library(AV_FOUNDATION_LIBRARY AVFoundation)
        find_library(WEBKIT_LIBRARY WebKit)
   
        find_library(ZLIB z)
        find_library(ICONVLIB iconv)

        list(APPEND PLATFORM_SPECIFIC_LIBS
             ${UIKIT_LIBRARY}
             ${OPENGLES_LIBRARY}
             ${CORE_MOTION_LIBRARY}
             ${AVKIT_LIBRARY}
             ${CORE_MEDIA_LIBRARY}
             ${CORE_TEXT_LIBRARY}
             ${SECURITY_LIBRARY}
             ${CORE_GRAPHICS_LIBRARY}
             ${AV_FOUNDATION_LIBRARY}
             ${WEBKIT_LIBRARY}
             ${COCOS_APPLE_LIBS}
             ${ZLIB}
             ${ICONVLIB}
             #"/usr/lib/libz.dylib"
             #"/usr/lib/libiconv.dylib"
             )
    endif()
```

Added the ZLIB and ICONVLIB, and removed full path rows.

Comment: This is more like a hack. We need a proper solution to this problem. Have you tried installing the libraries using a package manager like Homebrew? Here are the links: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/libiconv and https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/zlib

Comment: This doesn't seem to work by itself. Was there anything else you edited ? I get a bunch of errors when I try this....

Comment: Here is what I did, instead of ${ZLIB}, I just did -lz, and instead of ${ICONVLIB} did -liconv

Answer (score 6):

you can fix this issue like this.

Other Linker Flags

libz.dylib => -lz 
libiconv.dylib => -liconv

good luck.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in cmake ?

Answer (score 3):

I have checked in the folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib

the files libz.dylib and libiconv.dylib doesn't exist. I think you should use the files libz.tbd and libiconv.tbd

[Project/Build Settings/Other Linker Flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9jWZ.png)

Comment: I removed them from build settings (other link flags) and added them to build phases. This manual solution works, thanks for that. But how can i do that with cmake?

Comment: you can refer in the {your_project_name}/cocos2d/cmake/Modules/CocosConfigDepend.cmake

Answer (score 2):

can `build setting` find linking and replace

step1

`/usr/lib/libz.dylib`

replace

> `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libiconv.dylib`

step2

`/usr/lib/libiconv.dylib`

replace

> `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libz.dylib`